# Event-based mailing with Redis, Python and PHP

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

I want to frequently publish messages to a Redis server from a Python component. Then, in an other PHP component that also has the access to this Redis server, I want to send emails to users based on the messages that are stored in Redis. If I'm not wrong, there are two ways of doing that: Push-Pull and Push-Push designs:

***Pull design***

The PHP component is frequently making requests to the Redis server, and when there is a new message, make the action.

***Push design:***

We don't need to make these frequent requests from the PHP component: Whenever a new message is published in Redis, the action from the PHP component can be triggered.

***My question***

How can we implement the Push-Push design? When I read the Redis documentation about the Pub-Sub model, I don't find anything about it. So I don't really understand how we can trigger an action, in an other way then making frequent requests to the redis server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run a "long-running" php process as daemon via using solutions such as `nohup`, `supervisor` or `upstart`. This process will keep working as daemon to consume your redis `channel`. Python will keep producing, php will keep consuming.

There are several libraries to run php process as daemon such as [reactphp](https://reactphp.org/) or if you are using a framework such as laravel, it offers a good pub/sub [interface](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redis#pubsub).

It will be something like this;

Php part will `subscribe` to `mychannel`

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SUBSCRIBE mychannel
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
1) "subscribe"
2) "mychannel"
3) (integer) 1
```

python will `publish` to `mychannel`

```
127.0.0.1:6379> publish mychannel myemailjson
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> publish mychannel myanotheremailjson
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

in the meanwhile, your php process will receive that messages

```
1) "message"
2) "mychannel"
3) "myemailjson"
1) "message"
2) "mychannel"
3) "myanotheremailjson"
```

In that `subscriber` php process you will call/trigger/dispatch your email delivery jobs(probably asynchronously) whenever it receives a message.

Comment: Alright, so this is the Push design because this php process will call the email delivery jobs? In a Pull design, that's the email component which would call the Redis server?

Comment: actually php part consists of let's say two classes - main class will listen that channel, whenever it receives a message it will call `MailDelivery` class's `send` method. @nolw38

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot that's clear. Feel free to upvote if you think the question was specific enough :)

Comment: @nolw38 i was one of the two upvoters ;) you are welcome.